# Using Regex to parse a string in cpp and creating a map

Tags: c++, regex

In cpp: 
I am trying to parse a string given that is built such as - "x=3.5;y=9.5"
Where I need to parse the x, and it value while using regex and building a MAP between x and its value 3.5, same goes for y and 9.5.
Variable name must start with a char a-z then it can contain under-score, numbers and chars. The delimiter between variables is ';'

Comment: Parsing a cpp source code ?

Comment: C++ is not a regular language.

Comment: Specifically, C++ can't be parsed by regular expression because it recurses. If I put an expression like "x + (y * 2)", the tokens between the parenthesis have to be parsed like a whole new expression. A regular expression can't do that. On top of that, C++ a really bad target to learn how to write parsers - it has some of the most complicated syntax of any language thanks to 5 decades of backwards compatibility and new features. All that said, if your "C++ source" is some generated file that is *guaranteed* to look like the way you described it, then a regex can help, but please confirm that.

Comment: yes it's will be in the exact format I stated.

Answer (score 1):

As you  mentioned, I'm going to assume your input files are guaranteed to look the way you described - otherwise, C++ is far too complex to parse in general with regular expressions.

You should make a regex pattern for a single assignment, and use `sregex_iterator` to step through it.

I'll adapt the example here:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator

```cpp
std::regex declare_pattern(R"(([a-zA-Z_]\w*)=(\d+\.\d*);?)");
std::string input("x2=2;_y=5.2");

auto declare_begin = std::sregex_iterator(input.begin(), input.end(), declare_pattern);
auto declare_end = std::sregex_iterator();

for (std::sregex_iterator i = declare_begin; i != declare_end; ++i) {
    std::smatch match = *i;                                                 
    std::cout << match[1] << " is " << std::stof(match[2]) << '\n';
}
```

Breaking down the regular expression

- `R"(...)"` - This is a raw string, so I can use backslashes without the compiler trying to escape them
- `([a-zA-Z_]\w*)` - this is a variable. The content in brackets matches one alphabetical character or underscore. `\w*` matches zero or more "word" characters (which is a-z, A-Z, _, and 0-9). The surrounding parenthesis means we're going to "capture" it, or record it so I can access it with `match[N]` later.
- `=` - literally the character "="
- `(\d+\.\d*)` matches a VERY simple float like "42.123". You'll need a more complicated pattern to match all the different ways C++ has to express a number, scientific notation, etc.
- `;?` - *optionally* matches a semicolon, to separate declarations

This does zero validations. Handles zero quirks like whitespace, etc. After a certain level of complexity you should consider trying to do traditional parsing. I like [PEGLTL](https://github.com/taocpp/PEGTL), which can describe simple patterns without overwhelming people with formal notation or concepts:

```cpp
struct number : seq< plus<digit>, one<'.'>, plus<digit> > {};
struct assignment : seq< identifier, one<'='>, number > {};
struct var_list : list< assignment, one<';'> > {};
/*...*/
memory_input in( "x=2.2;y=3", "" );
auto result = parse< var_list >( in );
```